# Volley Library. Where I'm wrong with the Response Listener?

Tags: kotlin, android-volley

Where I'm wrong with this code? 
The Response it's always on ErrorListener.. 
But I'm not able to understand why. 
I'm passing the correct parameters of the API.

```
     val jsonobj = JSONObject()


        loginBtn.setOnClickListener {
            jsonobj.put("mail", mailTxt.text)
            jsonobj.put("pass", passTxt.text)
            val que = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)
            val req = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonobj,
                    Response.Listener{
                        toast("Yes")
                   }, Response.ErrorListener {
                toast("Error")
            })
            que.add(req)
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: If `ErrorListener` is firing then it is your server giving you an error.

Comment: I'm using the same API with Postman and with the same params, but it's work perfectly.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot from your postman?

Comment: Also do you have the Internet Permission in your manifest?

Comment: I'm a completely idiot. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the Internet permission

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```